# Removing an item from a toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a menubar at the top of my application.

Adding a username to the menu is no problem, however removing a username seems to be different. I use this code to add an item to the menu:

```
usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
```

Like I said it works fine and immediately adds the username to the menu. However when I try to remove an item from the menu it doesn't instantly remove it and I have to restart my application.

So: What do I have to change so it instantly removes the string from the textbox from the dropdownitems? I save the usernames in the `Properties.Default.Settings.Usernames`. Is there a reason why it instantly adds a menuitem but when I try to remove one I have to restart my application first?

**EDIT:**
Code to remove an item:

```
private void oKToolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(toolStripTextBox4.Text))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter the username you would like to delete in the textbox., "Error");
       return;
     }
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Usernames.Contains(toolStripTextBox4.Text) == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The username you're trying to delete does not exist.", "Error");
    toolStripTextBox4.Clear();
    return;
}
usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey(toolStripTextBox4.Text);
Properties.Settings.Default.Usernames.Remove(toolStripTextBox4.Text);
toolStripTextBox4.Clear();
```

}

Comment: Post the code to show how you try to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `RemoveByKey` method, you need to set `ToolStripItem.Name` property. While adding item, use the following code.

```
var tsi = usernamesToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(toolStripTextBox3.Text);
tsi.Name = toolStripTextBox3.Text;
```